# Aligning content size of header and main

Tags: html, css

There are sites like https://tagesschau.de and https://www.atlassian.com/ where the header background spans the complete page width, but the content of the header is only as wide as the content of the main area.

It's easy to create two areas of same width and put them below each other, but I am wondering how at the same time the background of the header (and also the main area) can span the complete width. Must have to do something with positioning and z-index, but I didn't get it using Devtools. Anyone can shed some light on this?

[image]

Update: Well, it's even the same for Stackoverflow itself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a couple of approaches to get such a result. There's an option to have all content of your site in single container with fixed width and add ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to some of the section but simpler method is less error prone in my opinion.

Let's take Atlassian site for our example.
Every section has 100% body width. Inside of every section (f.e. header) sits another div with 100% parent width - this one is responsible for section's background. Inside of this elements there's another div (f.e. global-nav--wac__row) with fixed width (or max-width for responsiveness) where header's content is. You can set it's `margin: 0 auto;` to have it centered. You don't have to add any background to this div and do same thing with every section of your site.

Please let me know if this answer is satisfying all right for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the [tagesschau.de](https://www.tagesschau.de/) they have :

**html**

```
<body class="tagesschau structurenode-tagesschau tsIndex">
  <div id="header">
     <div class="wrapper">
     </div>
  <div id="content">
     <div class="wrapper" role="main">
     </div>
</body>
```

*for the main background*

```
body.tagesschau {
    background: #015999 url(../img/tagesschau/background/base.jpg) repeat-x 
    fixed top;
}
```

*for the header background*

```
.tagesschau #header {
   background: url(../img/base/masternavi/mn_tagesschau.png) repeat-x 0 -65px;
}
```

`body`, `#header`, and `#content` **width are set to 100%**
Here `#header` and `#content` are direct children of `body`, and they both have, as direct only child, a div with the same `.wrapper` class.
The `.wrapper` class is defined with :

```
.wrapper {
  width: 1008px;  /* depending on screen size it goes 762, 480 and 320px */
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

The `#header` and `#content` 'content' is *wrapped* the same way which gives this visual effect

Comment: thanks. could you add some HTML, soe have a complete example like the one from Yor? :-)

Comment: What they did is actually like Yor described, with only names to change. The parent is `body` (instead of `.wrapper`), the children are `#header` and `#content` (instead of `.header` and `.main`), and the content is in `.wrapper` (instead of `.container`)

Comment: Done. Why they don't use the header or main tag i don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you should have the same container for the header and main something like

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
     Header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
    Main
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

Comment: thank you, that looks liek the correct answer. I am wondering who downvoted it and why. waiting for some further feedback, maybe there is some aspect I am currently missing. Likely to select this as answer, if no one finds a fault with that.

Comment: Not really sure why its got downvoted. Newbie here in Stackoverflow haha. Theres really some other way to get the same result but this is the most commonly used and safest way to do this.